# Commuting real operators

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's clear that if two operators in $\mathbb{C^n}$ are commuting then they have a common eigenvector and a basis in which they are upper triangularizable (simultaneously). Of course, in $\mathbb {R^n}$ it's wrong but how we can generalize result from $\mathbb{C^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$? Possible there are necessary and sufficient conditions (if we know that two operators are commuting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two real matrices share a non-real eigenvector $z$ over $\mathbb C$, they also share the eigenvector $\overline{z}$ and in turn, the real-linear span of the real and imaginary parts of $z$ is a two-dimensional invariant subspace of both matrices. So, in the real case, the analogue of simultaneous triangularisation is a simultaneous *block-triangularisation*, where each diagonal block is either $1\times1$ or $2\times2$.